# How to automatic set constraints to make a uniform distance between UIViews?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've a ViewController that have some components, UILabels and UITextFields. I wants that the distance between them is uniform, 2 Points Top and Bottom, for example. So far, I adjust manually the distance. I wants know if exists a way to make this automatically. I tried select all UIViews and set constraints, but not works.

Actually layout:

[image]

When I tried set all components constraints:

[image]

Not works perfectelly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wants that the distance between them is uniform, 2 Points Top and Bottom, for example.

For this kind of work `UIStackView` do the best job. Simply select all view, check `Embed In Stack`:

[image]

And then specify the `Spacing` value (note, that sometimes you also need to change the `Axis` parameter, but in most cases initial value is correct for your ui elements):

[image]

Result (distance between all labels is 8):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't set that constant spacing by selecting all components , but you can insert them inside a Vertical `UIStackview` (emebded in a `UIScrollView` ) with distribution `fillEqually` and set `spacing` between items to any constant you want

```
-> mainView
   -> scrollView
      ->contentView   
         ->stackview
            ->lbl1
            ->txtf1
```

Comment: I really need embed this in `UIScrollView`? I've a UIView, but option Embed in -> StackView is not able.

Comment: yes it has to be inside a scrollview as items total height may exceed some device's height , i know it's silly to re create constraints but it's more easier than your current approach so insert it from object library

Comment: You answer is correct, but the other is more simple.

Comment: Note that stackView only is not sufficient you need to embed it inside a scrollview to avoid trimming issues

Comment: Oh yes, I've noted this running app in differnts screens.